# How to handle exception state in activiti bpmn

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

How activiti handles the exception state? If error occurs in any of the task how the flow will move back to a step from where the task can be re executed again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of answers to this question.
If the task is a java or script task and is running synchronously, then resumption of a failed instance (usually caused by a technical exception) with be from the last persisted state (remember, a BPM engine is really just a state machine).

Now, you can (obviously) add exception handlers (especially in 5.15 which introduces event handlers) for a specific task or for the process instance as a whole. These exception handler allow you to control transaction rollback (depends on the transaction manager you are using).

Finally, you can bubble a bpmnEvent up to the process model and handle exceptions/compensation using an attached/boundary event handler in the BPMN model.

Hope this helps.
Greg Harley.